# connecting to remote host and perform operation

Tags: python, linux, database, ssh

I have requirement to connect to one remote host and perform set of operation using python script like grep for files and check whether DB is running or not .

This what sample code i got

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST="yyy03xxx.us.kkk.com"
# Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
COMMAND="uname -a"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
```

Please suggest how can i modify this code to multiple operation

Comment: single host multiple operation on that host

Comment: Right. Okay, so update `COMMAND`, and run the same code, basically

Comment: i don't want to use one command like this COMMAND="uname -a"

Comment: By the way, `"%s" % HOST` doesn't make sense. It can just be `HOST` there

Comment: update COMMAND not clear ..could you please brief .

Comment: You say you don't want `uname -a`, so change it. Make it something different. Run the exact same code you have. Just change `COMMAND`. For example, `COMMAND="echo 'hello'; uname -a; echo 'world''"`

Comment: I want something like connect to db and check whether it is running ,run some query on that  and grep for some files in that host  .In single line I can do these things ?

Comment: Probably not, no. You can run many `subprocess.Popen`, though